# Getting an Error trying to add a user to mongodb 2.6.5

Tags: macos, mongodb, macports, mongo-shell

I have spent a majority of my day trying to add a user to mongodb 2.6.5.  I installed & re-installed Mongo via macports.

Try #1 (  `addUser();`  ):

```
1. # switching to the admin user
   > use admin

2. # db.addUser("admin", "password");
```

When use the `addUser();` I get this error:

```
WARNING: The 'addUser' shell helper is DEPRECATED. Please use 'createUser' instead 
2014-11-03T15:19:16.193-0500 Error: couldn't add user: User and role management
commands require auth data to have schema version 3 but found 1 at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1004
```

Try #2 ( `createUser();` ):

```
1. # switching to the admin user
   > use admin

2. # db.createUser("admin", "password");
```

When use the `createUser();` I get this error:

```
2014-11-03T15:25:38.243-0500 Error: couldn't add user: no such cmd: 0 at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1004
```

I have spent a lot of time looking up other people's questions and answers. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 11):

createUser expect a document and not a string literal. for example:

```
db.createUser( { "user" : "accountAdmin01",
                 "pwd": "cleartext password",
                 "customData" : { employeeId: 12345 },
                 "roles" : [ { role: "clusterAdmin", db: "admin" },
                             { role: "readAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
                             "readWrite"
                             ] },
               { w: "majority" , wtimeout: 5000 } )
```

Or

```
db.createUser(
   {
     user: "accountUser",
     pwd: "password",
     roles: [ "dbAdmin", "userAdmin" ]
   }
)
```

Refer [db.createUser()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/) for more information

However before you add the user check if the auth schema exists by executing:

```
db.system.users.find()
```

If it does not return anything then you need create the schema by executing:

```
db.system.users.insert({
  "roles" : [ "userAdmin", "dbAdmin"],
  "userSource":"$external", 
  "user" : "dbadmin"
})
```

You should not get error while adding the user once the schema is generated.

Or if you have upgraded to MongoDb 2.6 version, then you need to upgrade the auth schema by executing:

```
db.getSiblingDB("admin").runCommand({authSchemaUpgrade: 1 })
```

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly. I'm new to mongo and maybe you might see something I am doing wrong. I have posted a gist of my terminal window : https://gist.github.com/rvirvo/622891629c946535b23f

Comment: What roles do you want to assign to this user?

Comment: I would like to assign the role of admin, or userAdmin.

Comment: Thanks ARS! I ended up getting it. I had to update the schema db.getSiblingDB("admin").runCommand({authSchemaUpgrade: 1 }); then I could create the user